# mt_rand expects parameter 2 to be integer, wrongly thinks float was given

Tags: php, xampp

```
mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

> Warning: mt_rand() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given in E:\Projects\school\users\temp.php on line 6

PHP 7.0.2 in XAMPP. This code was running fine in last XAMPP installation which had 5.x. So the update broke it. Can't find anything on google.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/5SjLL

Comment: That's strange, I have the page loaded in front of me that has the error on it. Curious.

Comment: Anything over 2147483647 will be a float automatically on a 32 bit system. Check out [Interger overflow](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: I can't seem to force PHP 7.0.2 to create this warning: `error_reporting(E_ALL); var_dump(mt_rand(1.5, 2.5));`

Comment: But it's running fine in older versions right now in production. I just upgraded and it broke down. So mt_rand is now more strict now I guess.

Comment: 32-bit PHP v 64-bit PHP

Comment: Ah, here's code to trip it on 64-bit PHP, not sure why it doesn't happen with explicit floats: `error_reporting(E_ALL); var_dump(mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999999999999));`

Comment: @MarkBaker That seems to be it I guess.

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually I just checked the older version of php was also x86. So is the new one. Both have `PHP_INT_MAX` of 214783647. So the only thing that changed is php version. The code is working fine in older version. I don't recall changing any php.ini setting either.

Answer (score 16):

Large ints are stored as floats if they overflow the maximum int value on the operating system of your server.  On 32-bit systems, they overflow above 2147483647.  On 64-bit systems, they overflow above 9223372036854775807.

You can use var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX) if you want to see the max int on your server.

If you want to ensure that it doesn't overflow regardless of the system it is running on, you can use mt_getrandmax() as your second argument

```
mt_rand(1000000000, mt_getrandmax())
```

Comment: Actually I just checked the older version of php was also x86. So is the new one. Both have `PHP_INT_MAX` of 214783647. So the only thing that changed is php version. The code is working fine in older version. I don't recall changing any php.ini setting either.

Answer (score 0):

**Change parameter 2 to be integer.**

```
mt_rand(1000000000, 8888888888);
```